# How can I tell whether or not a function f can be a probability density function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Consider the function:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 c(2x - x^3),& 0<x\lt \frac{5}{2}\\
 \\
 \;0 &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$

I need to determine whether or not this can be a probability density function. My first step was to find $C$, by taking the integral of the function $c(2x - x^3)$, from $\frac{5}{2}$ to $0$, and setting it equal to 1 to find $C$.

Comment: Did you check that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$?

Comment: *MUST BE NON-NEGATIVE* and integrate to $1.0$.